# Fiat uno fire 1100

Tags: ignition

I'm having trouble with my car not starting.

I bought a new coil and a new module, and cleaned the distributor, but I'm still without luck.

What else can it be?

And then I want to know on your coil you have the middle wire which is the ignition wire and then you have the two on the side of it which goes to the module, must both of them have continuous power or just the one even with the module plugged out both of the still have continuous power.

Comment: What happens when you try to start the car?

Comment: The motor just turns a few times fast then its like the battry is dead